# The difference between "100" and "100px" in html

Tags: html, canvas

i was about to create a html5 canvas the size of 500px*500px:

```
<canvas id="stone" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

and stroke a line from (70px, 70px) to (140px, 140px) on it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById( "stone" );
var context;

try {
    context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
} catch( e ) {
    $( "support" ).html( "HTML5 canvas is not supported by your browser." );
}

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo( 70, 70 );
context.lineTo( 140, 140 );
context.stroke();
```

but i was given a square with the line that wasn't start at (70px, 70px) obviously:
[image]

i thought there was somethings wrong with the size of my canvas, so i removed the suffix "px" from width and height property of canvas and kept others unchanged:

```
<canvas id="stone" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

and i got a rectangle with a right positioned line this time:
[image]

what's the difference between "500" and "500px"? how can i make this canvas a right size?

Comment: px is unit of css, so I suppose 500px in height attribute is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width):

> The `canvas` element has two attributes to control the size of the coordinate space: `width` and `height`. These attributes, when specified, must have values that are **valid [non-negative integers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#non-negative-integers)**. The rules for parsing non-negative integers must be used to obtain their numeric values. If an attribute is missing, or if parsing its value returns an error, then the default value must be used instead. The width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150.

Lengths in HTML are *always* unit-less. Length units are part of CSS and thus don't appear in HTML (except for `style`).